# How to add subtitles with Handbrake

Tags: video, avi, subtitles, handbrake, video-conversion

I'm trying to add subtitles to an AVI using handbrake. The subtitles are stored in an .srt file. The output file is MP4. After I run the conversion everything completes without error but when I watch the video subtitles aren't showing. I have tried checking the different options for the subtitles, but it doesn't make any difference. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to handbrake idk, but here's a sample mencoder command
`mencoder -vop pp=de,scale=548:222 -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavcopts keyint=25:vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=679:vpass=1 -sub "Domino.srt" -o "Domino_with_subs.avi" "Domino.avi"`

from here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/subtitle-encoding-mencoder-501902/

Comment: if you need to compile mencoder i have a tut on my blog: aking1012.blogspot.com

Comment: Works, but the aspect ratio gets messed up. Everything is stretched horizontally and there is blank space on the top and the bottom.

Comment: you'll need to change scale probably, or leave it out

Comment: The  original video is 720x480. I tried that and got the blank lines on the sides like before. Then I changed the scale to 720,400, because I saw Handbrake do that and it worked. Why does changing the scale from 720x480 to 720x400 fix the problem?

Comment: good question...idk

Comment: How can I make the subtitles appear thicker?

Comment: you could try a different font or scale...$ mplayer -subfont-text-scale 3 /path/to/your/video as referenced here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=17783

Comment: I increased the vbitrate to 4000 and the quality still isn't as good as I'd like. The output file is half the size of the original. What other settings can I use to increase the video quality?

Comment: instead of -ovc lavc -lavcopts  eyint=25:vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=679:vpass=1 try -ovc copy

Comment: When I do that the video quality is preserved but then why don't the subs show up anymore?

Comment: ah, my bad....hmm, not sure other than turning up the bitrate even further or changing the codec from mpeg4 to something less lossy

Comment: What's a better codec to use? I tried x264 and it said it couldn't find the video filter.

Comment: if it can't find the video filter then x264 probably isn't compiled in to the version of mencoder you are using if you keep the lavc stuff and just change codec to huffyuv it should be lossless, but it will probably get huge: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-enc-libavcodec.html

Comment: None of the codecs I've tried worked. How can I see which codecs are available?

Comment: within the lavc package i don't know...the page i linked to has a list that should work...if it doesn't i'm not so sure beyond jacking the bitrate way up